# this.props.dispatch() undefined using recompose lifecycle({})

Tags: reactjs, redux, decorator, redux-form, recompose

So I'm trying to move my lifecycle methods into an HOC decorator using Recompose. Something like this...

```
export const fetchOptions= lifecycle({  
  componentDidMount() {
     this.props.dispatch(change('mainForm', 'orderHeader.proxies', this.props.currentSalesRepId));
  },

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.total != prevProps.total){
      this.props.dispatch(change('mainForm', 'totalPurchase', this.props.total));
    }
  }
 });
```

Then I'm trying to add it to my form component which renders all my markup. Like this.

```
export default compose(
  connect(mapState, mapDispatch),
  fetchOptions,
)(MainReduxForm)
```

I keep getting an error that this.props.dispatch is not a function... Any thoughts? I purposely kept this brief to avoid a text wall. If you need additional info just let me know!

Comment: What does `mapDispatch` look like? Are you injecting `dispatch` into the props?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that the `dispatch` method will only be added automatically to your props if you don't provide a `mapDispatchToProps` function or in your case. `mapDispatch`

So you have two option, remove `mapDispatch` from your connect call.

```
export default compose(
  connect(mapState),
  fetchOptions,
)(MainReduxForm)
```

or if you are doing something inside your `mapDispatch` simply add dispatch to your return object

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        dispatch,
        ...
        other dispatch functions here
        ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! adding dispatch in mapDispatch took care of the issue! Don't know why I didn't think of that!